# Delete multiple lines from a file by finding a key

Tags: python, perl, shell

Suppose I have the following lines in a file (don't consider it an XML file):

```
<AVP code="123" name="abcd">
    <type>
        <high/>
    </type>
</AVP>
<AVP code="234" name="ukbkj">
    <type>
      <enum/>
    <type>
       <enum name="erdf"/>
 </AVP>
```

I would like to delete from (for example) AVP code 123 to the matching /AVP, so that all data for AVP 123 should be deleted. How can I achieve this?
Here's what the output should look like.  I would like to save to a file, not print to standard output.

```
<AVP code="234" name="ukbkj">
    <type>
       <enum/>
    <type>
       <enum name="erdf"/>
 </AVP>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand. Please include in your question 1) the desired output, 2) the Python or Perl code you have tried, 3) the actual output you get.

Comment: he was trying to delete the whole block.

Comment: I need in python script

Comment: This is not supposed to be XML? Is it `<high\>` or `<high/>`? Does the document have a root element?

Comment: Do you know how to use a SAX parser?  (`xml.sax` module)  Listen for the node(s) that match what you want, ignoring them, and pass anything else through.

Comment: Is this supposed to be XML?  If so, please correct your sample.  If not, please say so.

Comment: its a xml file only..

Comment: No, it is not valid XML. Please include the real input file.

Comment: NOW IT CORRECTED...@LutzHorn

Comment: Nope; it's still wrong.  You have unclosed `type` tags.

Comment: Just for wrong insert of a slash. U have down voted. It dont show that u r good Explainer. @LutzHorn

Comment: I downvoted because your question "does not show any research effort". Please don't post questions asking for code without showing what you have tried.

Comment: I tried to insert multiple line based on taking input from user and that working fine. Here i typed the code in speed so by mistake wrong slash symbol came. But from the code is well understood the its a xml code only.

Comment: @EricHughes I am sorry that i have put the code in first attempt as i was typing in speed and i press tab button and accidently it went to post button and i pressed enter by mistake. which posted the question without code. If possible please upvote my question.

Comment: Do you really think somebody will upvote your question because you *ask* him? You gain upvotes if people think that your question shows research effort and is useful and clear. It didn't and it isn't.

Comment: @vishalkumar The XML is still wrong, you still haven't shown any effort to solve your own problem, and I don't think it's a very useful question.  I didn't vote to close it, because I don't think it's inappropriate, I just don't think it's a very good question.  Sorry.

Comment: @EricHughes what error do u see in the question please explain..

Comment: @vishalkumar Please see my earlier comment, which is still valid.  You have unclosed `type` tags.  In XML, every tag needs to be self-closing `<selfClosing />` or needs to be explicitly closed `<aTag> <!-- stuff --> </aTag>`.  Please also note that Stack Overflow encourages a less casual tone--this includes spelling out "you" instead of "u", starting sentences with a capital letter, and using punctuation.  See [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

Through perl.

```
$ perl -0777pe 's/<AVP code="123".*?<\/AVP> *\n//sg' file
<AVP code="234" name="ukbkj">
<type>
<enum\>
<type>
<enum\>
<AVP code>
```

Through python.

```
import re
with open('file') as f:
    m = f.read()
    splt = re.findall(r'(?s)<AVP\s+code="\d+".*?</AVP>', m)
    for i in splt:
        if '<AVP code="123"' not in i:
            print(i, end="")
```

Comment: Perhaps it should look for a closing `</AVP>` tag instead of the next AVP element: what if the one he wants to delete is the last one in a sequence?  Won't this then gobble up all of the rest of the document?

Comment: Better; guess the OP wants python, even though he put the perl tag on it...

Comment: Its Good if some one can tell in perl script also. this will help to know perl, that so why i put perl and shell tag also.. @EricHughes

Comment: added python code also.

Comment: @vishalkumar Then this answer does what you need.  Perhaps delete your comment that says "I need in python script" and accept this answer, or explain why it doesn't work the way you want.

Comment: @EricHughes could you revert the downvote?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I didn't downvote your answer, just the question because I thought it poorly articulated and showing a distinct lack of a real attempt at solving the problem.  And the XML is invalid.

Comment: Regular expression for XML parsing is known to cause all kind of bad things (I wont't link to the well known answer because such a link is forbidden here in SO).

Comment: @LutzHorn yep, i think op knows the consequences of parsing xml files with regex.

Comment: I doubt. From his comments above I get the impression that he doesn't even know XML syntax.

Comment: someone says that the provided xml is not a valid one. I think xml parsers would read only the valid xml files.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Hi Avinash.. Whatever u gave me code of python to delete avp is not totally correct. this doesn't delete the avps from file.

Answer (score 0):

**If** your input would be XML, it would look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <AVP code="123" name="abcd">
        <type>
            <high/>
        </type>
    </AVP>
    <AVP code="234" name="ukbkj">
        <type>
          <enum/>
        </type>
        <type>
           <enum/>
        </type>
     </AVP>
</root>
```

You could use this XSLT to remove all `AVP` elements.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="AVP[@code='123']" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Apply it using Python:

```
import lxml.etree as ET

dom = ET.parse("avp.xml")
xslt = ET.parse("avp.xslt")
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(dom)
with open("avp-out.xml", "wb") as o:
    o.write(ET.tostring(newdom, pretty_print=True))
```

Output in `avp-out.xml`:

```
<root>

    <AVP code="234" name="ukbkj">
        <type>
          <enum/>
        </type>
        <type>
           <enum/>
        </type>
     </AVP>
</root>
```

Comment: As u have explained me by using xslt. but code can be different(it will be ask by user ) So here how we can pass user input code to xslt.

Answer (score 0):

The more appropriate way to do this would be using an XML parsing library, [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML) is a good one. Note, your current example is *not* valid XML:

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 

use XML::LibXML;

my $xml_filename = $ARGV[0];
die "Missing name of xml file to parse"
   unless $xml_filename;
open(my $xml_file, '<', $xml_filename) 
   or die "Error opening XML file: $!";

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(IO => $xml_file);
foreach my $node ( $dom->findnodes('/root/AVP') ) {
   $node->unbindNode()
      if $node->getAttribute('code') == 123;
}

open(my $out_fh, '>', "${xml_filename}.out") 
   or die "Unable to open outfile: $!";
binmode $out_fh;    

# write XML tree to file
$dom->toFH($out_fh);
close($out_fh);
```

Answer (score 0):

With [`XML::Twig`](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.48/Twig.pm) - copying the fixed XML that Lutz Horn mentioned:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

sub delete_if_code_123 {
    my ( $twig, $AVP ) = @_;
    if ( $AVP->att('code') eq "123" ) {
        $AVP->delete;
    }
}

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    pretty_print  => 'indented',
    twig_handlers => { 'AVP' => \&delete_if_code_123 },
);

$twig ->parse( \*DATA );

$twig -> print;


__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <AVP code="123" name="abcd">
        <type>
            <high/>
        </type>
    </AVP>
    <AVP code="234" name="ukbkj">
        <type>
          <enum/>
        </type>
        <type>
           <enum/>
        </type>
     </AVP>
</root>
```